# How to fix navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

am trying to make my navigation bar fixed when I scroll but its not working, what's wrong wit my code?

```
let nav_offset_top = $('.navbar').height() + 50;

function navbarFixed() {
    if ($('.navbar').length) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            let scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= nav_offset_top) {
                $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed')
            } else {
                $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed')
            }enter code here
        })
    }
}
navbarFixed();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your HTML and CSS look like, but jQuery is working fine.

```js
let nav_offset_top = $('.navbar').height() + 50;

function navbarFixed() {
  if ($('.navbar').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      let scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= nav_offset_top) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed')
      } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed')
      }
    })
  }
}
navbarFixed();
```

```css
.navbar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">Menu</div>
<div style="height:1000px">Demo</div>
```

Comment: my CSS is also fine do you want to have a look at it

Comment: @HillaryOkello What you need to do is post your code that recreates the issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

This adds a class when the user scrolled the page. Based on that class you can make your navbar fixed in you `CSS`.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var $nav = $("nav");
        $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
    });
});
```